# Обработка события на нажатия клавиш в консоли C++

Tags: c++, c, события, консоль, клавиатура

Не понимаю, как сделать обработку событий при нажатии кнопки в консоли на C++.
Причём, чтобы эта кнопка на клавиатуре была именно та, которую я укажу, то есть не просто нажатие любой клавиши, а определённой. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Добрый день! Предоставьте пожалуйста Ваш код, где у Вас не получается обрабатывать именно ту самую кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <conio.h>

//...

char c = _getch();
    
if (c == 'w') {
    // была нажата клавиша 'w'
}
```

Comment: conio? вы еще бы что то древнее взяли бы

Comment: @Maggot а что бы вы использовали?

Comment: ncurses \ PDCurses